# How can I pull all values of a repeating key from a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, key

So I am currently querying a huge list of Json Objects (2,000 to be exact). Within the query or URI I am using it pulls thousands of objects that share the same key values. How do you pull all of the values from one specific key? So If I want to pull all the "id": values and log those, how do I do that?

The other problem I have is the object obviously maintains no specific order and the values of those keys are constantly changing, so using dot notation to parse through an array doesn't really work. Here is my example code.

```
function myFunction() {
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("API QUERY")
   
  
  var content = res.getContentText();

  var json = JSON.parse(content);

  var jobId = json["items"][0]["name"]

  var values = Object.keys(jobId).map(function (key) { return jobId[key]; });

Logger.log(values)

};
```

The response looks like this:

```
{
"items": [
{
"id": ,
"name": "My job name",
"status": "open",
"created": 153173990000,
"finished": 153174000000,
"tracking": "https://api/not-a-real-tracking-link",
"group": 6417500000,
"site": {},
"progress": 0,
}
]
}
```

And then it repeats 2000 times on after the other

```
{
"items": [
{
"id": ,
"name": "My job name2",
"status": "open",
"created": 153173990000,
"finished": 153174000000,
"tracking": "https://api/not-a-real-tracking-link",
"group": 6417500000,
"site": {},
"progress": 0,
}
]
}

{
"items": [

{
"id": ,
"name": "My job name3",
"status": "open",
"created": 153173990000,
"finished": 153174000000,
"tracking": "https://api/not-a-real-tracking-link",
"group": 6417500000,
"site": {},
"progress": 0,
}
]
}
```

So the query itself pulls 2000 objects just like this, I need the pull the values of the "name" key from each object and log them.

Comment: what is the format of the data - without that, we can only guess - by the way, `var jobId = json["items"][0]["name"]` is `var jobId = json.items[0].name` - because your `json` variable isn't JSON, it's just a plain ol' javascript object once you've parsed the JSON

Comment: Sorry, is that what you needed? I made an edit, and for example, I need the "name":

Comment: what is "repeating" ... you've shown a single item, so there is no repeating key

Comment: So in the query, I am pulling this data format 2000 times for different jobs, so there are 2000 instances with different key values. I am trying to pull all of those values and log them here at first.  Adding this to the code actually pulls the values, but they return as "null"
 let objKeys = Object.keys(content);

objKeys.forEach(item => {
 let value = content["items"];

Comment: so `let value = content["items"];` is null?

Comment: Correct. But If I do something like var jobId = json["items"][0]["name"]

Then Logger.log(jobId) - it only returns a single value and I need all of them.

Comment: but you're only accessing a single value - oh, `content` is JSON, and `json` is data, so you need `Object.keys(json)` - the variable names confuse the issue, since `content` is clearly the JSON string, and `json` is a javascript object, not a JSON string

Comment: See I tried that, it will return just ["items"] and all of that data, but if I try to move further down the tree like ["items"]["id"] it just returns as null.

Comment: `items` is an array - so it's `items[index].id` where `index` is a number, `0` to  `items.length - 1`

Comment: So this works, but it only pulls one single "id" instead of all of them. That is the issue I have.

Comment: yes, there's an id at index 0, 1, 2 ... etc your sample data only has one id ... so, hard to guess whats repeating

Comment: Is There a way to return the entire index?

Comment: `json.items[0]` is the whole object - what is "the entire index" ... you mean the "array" ... that's `json.items` then you can do things with that array, though, your data only has one element so, not sure what you want to do with it, and there's nothing repeating there, so, again, the question is vague

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help. Let me know if the above edit on the database example helps. It literally is the same Object repeating over and over inside a new array with different values for the keys. I need to pull the values from the "name" key and log them  for each individual object. The query itself that I fetch pulls 2000 instances of this data structure.

Comment: Json you posted is not valid. Pls post the valid one

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to stack values into a new object:

```js
const json = [
  {id: 123, value:"val a"},
  {id: 124, value:"val b"},
  {id: 125, value:"val c"},
  {id: 123, value:"val d"},
  {id: 125, value:"val e"},
  {id: 223, value:"val f"},
  {id: 123, value:"val g"},
  {id: 123, value:"val h"},
  {id: 123, value:"val i"},
  {id: 223, value:"val j"},
  {id: 223, value:"val k"},
];

console.log( json.reduce( (newObj, data) =>
{
  const array = newObj[data.id] = newObj[data.id] || []; //get already existing array or create a new one

  array[array.length] = data.value; //append value to the end of the array
  return newObj;
}, {} /* init newObj as empty object */ ));
```